# Algorithm for finding modulo given primitive root.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

It is conjectured by Artin that for every number $g$ which is not $-1$ and not a square number, there is an infinite number of $m$ such that $g$ is a primitive root modulo $m$.

How to find $m$ efficiently given primitive root $g$?

The reverse problem that given modulo $m$, find the primitive root $g$ can be solved faster than brute force with random trying with checking $g^{(m-1)/d} \neq 1$ ( $d\mid m$ ).

But I can't find something like that for this problem.

Comment: Sorry, that first statement is not known.  Well, as stated it is obviously false (take $g=1$ say).  See [Artin's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots)

Comment: I'm sorry. I edit the statement .Thank you for pointing out.